# Computing the probability using a joint density function

Tags: probability-distributions, multiple-integral, bivariate-distributions

I am in the middle of an exercise dealing with two random variables $(X,Y)$ having the bivariate normal density function:

$$f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}}\exp {\left[-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^{2})}(x^{2}-2\rho xy + y^{2})\right]}$$

The exercise problem asks :

(1) Show that $X$ and $Z=(Y-\rho X)/\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}$ are independent $N(0,1)$ variables, and

(2)Deduce that :

$$P(X>0,Y>0) =\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2\pi}\arcsin\rho$$

I am not correctly formulate the solution to part (2) of the problem.

One clever step is to write down the event $\{X>0,Y>0\}$ in terms of $(W,Z)$, because they are independent gaussians, and easier to integrate.

$$\{X>0,Y>0\} = \{W>0,Z>-\frac{\rho W}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\}$$

But, how to compute probabilities of such events of the type $\{X>a,Y>f(X)\}$.

For completeness, I reproduce my solution to part (1) of the problem.

***My Solution.***

Consider the map $T$ defined by:

\begin{align*}
w & =x\\
z & =\frac{(y-\rho x)}{\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}}
\end{align*}

The inverse map $T^{-1}$ is given by:

\begin{align}
x & =w\\
y & =\rho w+z\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}
\end{align}

The Jacobian $\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(w,z)}$ is given by:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(w,z)} & =\left|\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
\rho & \sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}
\end{array}\right|\\
 & =\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}
\end{align}

Hence, the joint density function of $(X,Z)$ is given by :

\begin{align}
f_{(W,Z)} &=f_{(X,Y)}(w,\rho w+z\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}})\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left( -\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^{2})}\left[w^{2}-2\rho w(\rho w+z\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}})+(\rho w+z\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}})^{2}\right]\right) \\
 & =\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left( -\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^{2})}\left[w^{2}-2\rho^{2}w^{2}+\rho^{2}w^{2}+z^{2}(1-\rho^{2})\right]\right) \\
 & =\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left( -\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^{2})}\left[w^{2}-\rho^{2}w^{2}+z^{2}(1-\rho^{2})\right]\right) \\
 & =\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left( -\frac{1}{2}(w^{2}+z^{2})\right) \\
 & =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left[-\frac{w^{2}}{2}\right]\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left[-\frac{z^{2}}{2}\right]
\end{align}

Consequently, $X$ and $Z$ are independent $N(0,1)$ random variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common trick for bivariate independent standard normals $(X, Z)$ is to use polar transformation. This is because of the presence of the term $x^2 + z^2$ in the joint pdf which is "related to circles" so to speak.

So a natural approach is to use polar transformation $(x, z) \to (r, \theta)$ which gives the pdf of the random variables $R, \Theta$ with supports $\mathbb{R}_+, (-\pi, \pi)$:
$$
f_{R, \Theta}(r, \theta) = \frac{r}{2\pi}e^{-r^2/2} \text{ for } r > 0, -\pi < \theta < \pi
$$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Now in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the Cartesian region $\{x > 0, z > -(\rho/\sqrt{1 - \rho^2})x\}$ gets transformed to the polar region $\{r > 0, \arctan(-\rho/\sqrt{1 - \rho^2}) < \theta < \pi/2\}$ and notice that $\arctan(-\rho/\sqrt{1 - \rho^2}) = -\arcsin(\rho)$.

So
\begin{align*}
\int\int_{\{x > 0, z > -(\rho/\sqrt{1 - \rho^2})x\}} f_{X, Z}(x, z) \ dxdz &= \int\int_{\{r > 0, -\arcsin(\rho) < \theta < \pi/2\}} f_{R, \Theta}(r, \theta) \ drd\theta \\
&=\int_{-\arcsin(\rho)}^{\pi/2} \underbrace{ \int_0^\infty  \frac{r}{2\pi}e^{-r^2/2} dr }_{\frac{1}{2\pi}} \ d\theta \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\Big(\frac{\pi}{2} + \arcsin(\rho)\Big) = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{\arcsin(\rho)}{2\pi}
\end{align*}

Comment: Finding the domain of integration in the $(r,\theta)$ space had me stumped for a while! All good now.